# Plotting data gridded by latitude and longitude

Tags: matlab, plot, datagrid

I'm currently trying to plot gridded lat, lon and no2 data. Attached is a reproducible and simplified version of the problem I'm having. When I use my attached code I recieve the error:

```
  Warning: Matrix dimensions must agree, not rendering mesh
```

I've tried using:

```
 [X Y] = meshgrid(y,yy)
```

which yielded the error:

```
 Error using checkGeolocatedDataGrid>checkMatrixSizes (line 54)
 LAT and LON dimensions do not agree with Z.
```

I've also tried meshing the grid with y, yy, and yyy and then using squeeze to remove a dimension from each variable.

```
 clc
 clear all
 close all

 a=.5;
 b=28;
 y = a.*randn(10,1)+b;

 aa = .5;
 bb = -95;
 yy = aa.*randn(10,1)+bb;

 aaa = .3;
 bbb = .6;
 yyy = aaa.*randn(10,1)+bbb;

 figure
 lonlim = [min(yy) max(yy)]
 latlim = [min(y) max(y)]
 usamap(latlim,lonlim)
 geoshow(y,yy,yyy,'DisplayType','Surface')
```

I'd like to be able to plot this data so that I can produce a figure that shows the value of variable 3 "yyy" as it corresponds to "y" and "yy" which are my "latitude and longitude" variables.

Thank you!

Comment: Currently your variables `y`, `yy`, and `yyy` are column vectors. According to the [geoshow documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geoshow.html) they should be M x N arrays. If I do `meshgrid()` on them, and generate a 10 x 10 dummy array for `yyy` it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! That ended up working to solve my example! While this example didn't quite solve my woes with my code (which is no fault of yours!) I appreciate you helping me to learn the ins and outs of this function!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to mesh the grids of y and yy and then change the dimensions of yyy!

```
clc
clear all
close all

a=.5;
b=28;
y = a.*randn(10,1)+b; % 10x10 class double

aa = .5;
bb = -95;
yy = aa.*randn(10,1)+bb; % 10x10 class double

aaa = .3;
bbb = .6;
yyy = aaa.*randn(10,10)+bbb; % 10x10 class double

[y, yy] = meshgrid(y,yy)

figure
lonlim = [min(yy) max(yy)]
latlim = [min(y) max(y)]
%usamap(latlim,lonlim)
geoshow(y,yy,yyy,'DisplayType','texturemap');
shading interp


 contourcbar
```